# Check if method is not called with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a void method that creates objects of type `Foo` and updates each entry of a list those objects.

When the list passed by parameter is empty it shouldn't create any object, thus not calling any setter method of class `Foo`.

```
public static void analyzeList(ArrayList<Something> list) {
    for (Something s : list) {
        Foo f = new Foo();

        f.setSomething(someMethod1(f));
        f.setSomething2(someMethod2(f));

        s.setFoo(f);
    }
}
```

So, I am trying to use Mockito to check that method `analyzeList(ArrayList<Something> list)` doesn't call any setter method of class `Foo`, but am having a hard time doing so, since I never worked with Mockito before.

I wrote this test:

```
@Test
public void shouldNotCallSettersWhenListIsEmpty() {
    Foo fooMocked = mock(Foo.class);
    FooLogic.analyzeList(emptyList);
    Mockito.verify(fooMocked, times(0)).setSomething(anyInt());
}
```

This test passes, and it should. But when I change `times(0)` to `times(1)`, the test keeps passing and it shouldn't, since the list is empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Foo` object you have in your test and the `Foo` objects you create in your `analyzeList` are different. You are creating a *new Foo* object each time in your code.

Even if you pass a non-empty list `Mockito.verify(fooMocked, times(0)).setSomething(anyInt());` will pass because you are not calling any methods on the mocked Foo instance.

But you say that by changing `times(0)` to `times(1)`, the test still passes. But the test should fail (can you re-check this)

With the current setup, you cannot verify anything on the created `Foo f` instances<sup>1</sup>. You can still verify the `setFoo` calls you make on `Something` if the list you pass has mock `Something` objects.

---

<sup>1</sup>unless you use Powermockito or something that allows you to mock `new` object creations in the code.

Comment: "But you say that by changing times(0) to times(1), the test still passes. But the test should fail (can you re-check this)" confirmed!! My mistake. Fixed the post.

Comment: @JoãoAlves He is absolutely correct. Your example can **not** work. That *mocked* Foo is **not** used by your production code. So, make sure you have a [mcve] for us. Then: A) either change your production code to not use new like this or B) use PowerMock(ito)/JMockit to gain control over `new()`

Answer (score 0):

In your situation,
I like to use the
`InOrder`
functionality;
specifically the
`InOrder.verifyNoMoreInteractions()`
method.

Here is an example:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.inOrder;

    import org.mockito.InOrder;

@Test
public void shouldNotCallSettersWhenListIsEmpty() {
    Foo fooMocked = mock(Foo.class);

    InOrder inOrderVariable = inOrder(fooMocked);

    FooLogic.analyzeList(emptyList);
    //Mockito.verify(fooMocked, times(0)).setSomething(anyInt());

    // Note: added example verify statement.
    inOrderVariable.verify(fooMocked).someMethod(paramaters)

    inOrderVariable.verifyNoMoreInteractions();
}
```

Comment: This seems to accomplish what I am looking for, but what if I  want to check interactions. Say, I send a list with some entries and not an empty list. Could I use this approach to check that the setter methods are called?

Comment: call InOrder.verify to define expected calls.  Do this before calling InOrder.verifyNoMoreInteractions.